# SpeechRecognizer onBeginningOfSpeech() **after** cancel()

Tags: android, android-speech-api

In my app's Logcat, I noticed that `SpeechRecognizer`'s [onBeginningOfSpeech()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener#onBeginningOfSpeech()) is sometimes called **after** [SpeechRecognizer.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#cancel()).

Assuming this is not a `SpeechRecognizer` bug, in what circumstances this should or could happen?

Is there a delay between [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#cancel()) and actual shutdown of the listener?

Answer (score 1):

The `onBeginningOfSpeech()` callback is called when the speech recognizer starts detecting speech in the audio stream being processed by it.

The `cancel()` method cancels any in-progress speech recognition, so onBeginningOfSpeech() should never occur after cancel() is called.

Most likely, there is a bug in your code that results in delay in the cancellation process.

Also, check very carefully that the `onBegninningOfSpeech()` you are seeing after `cancel()` does not belong to a previous recognizer start (incorrectly followed by another recognizer start, before `onEndOfSpeech()` or `onError()` arrived).